# mongoose model save does not trigger callback and pass to chai-http when collection does not exist in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I create an post api and use mongoose model to save the request data to database. Then I use postman to test this api. Everything works. Everything works I mean collection created, data saved to the collection, and get data from response. see the following code

```
    const eSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      model: String,
      year: Number,
      price: Number
    });

    const eModel = mongoose.model('bmw', eSchema);

    app.post('/api/bmw', (req, res) => {
      const newRecord = new eModel(req.body);
      newRecord.save((error, record) => {
        res.status(201).send(record);
      });
    });
```

Then I try to add test to this api. I use mocha with chai-http. see the following code

```
    let chai = require('chai');
    const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
    chai.use(chaiHttp);

    it('POST /api/bmw', () => {
      chai
      .request(app)
      .post('/api/bmw')
      .send({ model: '440i', year: 2018, price: 85000 })
      .end((error, res) => {
        console.log('POST', res.body);
      });
    });
```

Step1: Drop database (no db, no collection)

Step2: I run the test using mocha path-to-test-file --timeout 20000

Step3: repeat the step2

After step 2, I do not see any logged data(console.log('POST', res.body)). however, the collection has been created and data has been saved to mongo database.

After step3, I do see the logged data. I assume because the collection already exists in mongo base on the step2.

Then I do one step further. I repeat from step1 to step3. but this time I put a log in the model save callback, then I realized the callback is not called either after step2. But if I use postman instead of chai-http, it works everytime.

Does anyone has the same problem? Is this a capability issue between mongoose model and chai-http? Did I miss settings or anything?

Personally, I think it should work regardless the collection exists in mongo.

Answer (score 1):

that api send is an asynchronous request. you need to pass the `done` function into your `it()` block to flag completion...like the below:

```
let chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);

it('POST /api/bmw', (done) => {
  chai
  .request(app)
  .post('/api/bmw')
  .send({ model: '440i', year: 2018, price: 85000 })
  .end((error, res) => {
    if(error) done(error)
    else{
      console.log('POST', res.body);
      done();
    }
  });
});
```